# Make malloc fail voluntarily in order to test the cases when malloc fails

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

I've been creating tests for a simple program that I created. I always check if the allocation of memory using malloc fails using something like this

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * x);

if(!ptr){
    //...
    exit(1); // but it could also not terminate abnormally and do something else
}
```

But usually, for my programs at least, `malloc` never fails, and those I can't really deterministically test the cases when `malloc` fails.

My question is: how can I test a program for the case of a memory allocation failure, if I've not control on the fact if malloc will fail or not? What should I do to test deterministically when malloc fails?

Comment: You can create your own `malloc` function and inject it with `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: nbro, What is your OS? Is it linux + glibc? Glibc's malloc has `__malloc_hook` pointer to redefine malloc: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_hook.3.html. You can redefine malloc to your own version which will fail according to some random variable or to some internal state (fail every 1000th call), and in most cases it will just call standard malloc. Alternatively you may define some `ulimit`s on memory size and use standard malloc.

Comment: it is deprecated

Answer (score 6):

Fake a `malloc`:

```
#define malloc(...) NULL
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * x);
```

Comment: This seems to be a better solution with respect to what Douglas is suggesting... maybe I could even pass, say, the value of a directive at compile time or something similar, so that I don't have to add it manually to each `.c` whenever I want to test this failure of `malloc`? Any suggestions on how to do it, if possible (since I'm not that really expert in the preprocessor directives)?

Comment: Or `#define malloc(s) my_alloc(s)`  The implement `my_alloc(s)` with `calloc()` and maybe `rand()` to fail at odd times.

Answer (score 5):

When I needed to test memory allocation failures at different stages, I used a function `xmalloc()` like this:

```
static int fail_after = 0;
static int num_allocs = 0;

static void *xmalloc(size_t size)
{
    if (fail_after > 0 && num_allocs++ >= fail_after)
    {
        fputs("Out of memory\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    return malloc(size);
}
```

The test harness (part of the same source file) could set `fail_after` to any suitable value, and reset `num_allocs` to zero before each new test run.

```
int main(void)
{
    int no1 = 5;

    for (fail_after = 0; fail_after < 33; fail_after++)
    {
        printf("Fail after: %d\n", fail_after);
        num_allocs = 0;
        test_allocation(no1);
    }

    printf("PID %d - waiting for some data to exit:", (int)getpid());
    fflush(0);
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can arrange to call `xmalloc()` in lieu of the 'real' `malloc()`:

```
#define malloc(x)    xmalloc(x)
```

That would be placed after the definition of `xmalloc()` — though there are ways to work around that if need so be.  You can tweak things all sorts of ways: limit the total size too, arrange to fail every N<sup>th</sup> allocation, arrange to fail for N successive allocations after M successful ones, etc.

Comment: Detail: with your `xmalloc()`, `return 0;` is not a failure return when `size==0`.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to call malloc with a negative value like this:

```
malloc(-1);
```

This will make `malloc` return `NULL` and set `errno` to `12` ("Cannot allocate memory") accordingly.

To be honest this is not a "real" out-of-memory scenario, but i think for testing purposes this will do.

Comment: Perfect and reasonable! Compiler cusses: `warning: argument 1 value ‘18446744073709551615’ exceeds maximum object size 9223372036854775807 [-Walloc-size-larger-than=]`
What is it if not out-of-memory?